# How to store user uploaded images in S3 private bucket and shows it back in the application

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an android application in which there are options for the users to upload many images. I am planning to use S3 as my storage system for all these images. I will create a private bucket and will have folders inside it for each users. When the user uploads an image, I will create a presigned url and the app will be directly uploading the file to S3 using that URL. All good till now. My question is how will I show it back on the app? Since the bucket is private, directly using the file URL will not work as it needs authentication. One solution is to call S3 and generate a temporary signed URL which can be passed back to the application and it will display it. The problem with this case is that, suppose I am displaying a feed of user images (say 20 images), then I have to make 20 calls to generate the signed authenticated URL and pass it back to the application. I think we can pass everything as a batch also. But it doesn't feels right to call it every time to make a signed URL. Is there a better way to retrieve the images and shows it back without making lot of calls? I can generate a unique UUID as the file name so that it's not easily guessable and make the bucket public. But is it secure?

Comment: you can plan a wrapper API from back-end e.g. baseurl/userDP/<UserId> this will print content of file on s3 using AWS access key and secret and use the same url in image source.

Comment: But in that case, all the images will be passing through my EC2 instance. i.e, S3->Ec2->Application. This will cause unnecessary processing and bandwidth consumption